# Mesh is messed up during animation play

Tags: animation, armature

I have this 3d model and it's armature was separated, so I attached them together by: Ctrl + P and then To parent with Automatic weights. Now I have this issue that the mesh looks kinda broken or messed up when the animation plays. Anyone knows what the issue is? [image]

Comment: Nvm, the issue got fixed. Had to press M and then distance for anyone else facing this.